# How to check if my stiffness matrix is correct

Tags: finite-element, numerics, poisson

I built the stiffness matrix for the Poisson equation on a 2-dimensional domain with the shape of "almost" an octagon, using pyramid basis functions. I used almost to intend the fact that I have an "irregular" shape.

The mesh has been given to me by a **point matrix $P$** and a **connectivity matrix $T$**. In $P$ I have the points of the domain, while in the matrix $T$ I have in each entry the vertices of the triangles. On page 47 of [Larson & Bengzon book](http://matematicas.unex.es/~coco/Modelizacion/FEMLarson_Bengzon.pdf) (section *"Data Storage Structures"*) is explained better what I mean with a simple example.

Anyway, I implemented the assembly procedure as described on page 85 and I
obtain the right result for simple squared domains. I also tried to use the code for the $[0,1]$-interval with grid size $h$ and things are good.

Of course here the point matrix is made by a `linspace` from $0$ to $1$, while $T$ is a matrix like $$T =\begin{bmatrix} 1& 2&3  \\ 2&3&4\end{bmatrix} $$ and I end up with the usual Laplacian matrix (modulo a factor of $h$). So it's right.

*Now the main question:*

**How can I check that the matrix I obtain for the "irregular" domain is correct?**

I already checked it's symmetric, and since there were *Homogeneous Dirichlet* boundary conditions I followed the approach of [Wolfgang Bangerth](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/users/393/wolfgang-bangerth) explained [here](https://www.math.colostate.edu/~bangerth/videos/676/slides.21.6.pdf) at *slide 14* (approach 2a). After this, I computed the condition number $K$ of the matrix and it is $K \approx 6$.

Comment: Have you checked the Jacobian for irregular elements?

Comment: Yes, I precomputed the gradient since each gradient is a constant vector on each triangle. I also wrote the same routine in the book. One stupid questio: that algorithm for the assembly should work in every geometry, right?

Comment: Is my question bad-posed?

Comment: Yes, the assembly is the same for irregular elements. No, I don't think it is bad posted. My question has the purpose of helping, but is not complete enough to be an answer.

Comment: Okay, thank you. By the way, I used the MatLab command `assema` to see if the matrix is the same, but the MatLab stiffness matrix is even singular! (My matrix, as wrote above, has condition number equal to $6$. As far as I know, this is usual for matrix coming from finite element discretizations